# Клиент-серверное взаимодействие по протоколу TCP в C#

Tags: c#, сокет

Здравствуйте начал изучать C# и застрял на теме клиент-серверное взаимодействие.
Вот код:
'''

const string ip = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 8080;

```
        var tcpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

        var tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        tcpSocket.Bind(tcpEndPoint);
        tcpSocket.Listen(5);

        while (true)
        {
            var listener = tcpSocket.Accept();
            var byfer = new byte[256];
            var size = 0;
            var data = new StringBuilder();

            do
            {
               size =  listener.Receive(byfer);
                data.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byfer, 0, size));


            } while (listener.Available > 0);
            Console.WriteLine(data);

            listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Успех"));

            listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            listener.Close();
```

'''
Помогите разобраться за что отвечает каждая строка данного кода и как все это работает.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
          //задаем переменную, которая хранит айпишник и порт объекта, который будем слушать
            var tcpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
          //задаем переменную, которая хранит инфу о сокете
            var tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
          //Связывает объект Socket с конечной точкой
            tcpSocket.Bind(tcpEndPoint);
          //Устанавливает объект Socket в состояние прослушивания
            tcpSocket.Listen(5);
            while (true)
            {
          //Извлекает из очереди запрос на подкючение и реализует его
                var listener = tcpSocket.Accept();
                var byfer = new byte[256];
                var size = 0;
                var data = new StringBuilder();
                do
                {
         //Cчитывает данные из byfer и возвращает число успешно считанных байтов
                   size =  listener.Receive(byfer);
                    data.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byfer, 0, size));
                } while (listener.Available > 0);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
         //Отправляет на сокет сообщение (которое может быть отображено на странице браузера например, если мы сделает Httplistner)
                listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Успех"));
         //Закрывает сокет
                listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
         //Вырубаем прослушку (закрываем листнер)
                listener.Close();
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли.Как я понял Sockets это некий интерфейс для реализации передачи данных по сети,вот это я все понял.Но я не могу понять того когда клиент передает данные этому серверу в какую переменную заходят эти данные и что дальше с ними происходит,и как они выводятся на консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Как и всё в программировании, очень просто, но сперва не понятно.

---

Как работают сокеты? Можете представить свой компьютер как помпу, а сокеты – отверстия в этой помпе. У каждой помпы есть свой адрес – IP, к каждого сокета есть свой id – адрес помпы + порт. Зачем нужны сокеты? Для создания каналов. Если клиент хочет послать сообщение cерверу, например, `Hello, World!`, то он сперва должен создать канал. Он спамит запрос о создании канала на серверный сокет, серверный сокет же берёт и спамит просмотр своей очереди сообщений – не пришло ли что-нибудь. Да, это poling, и вы можете его вызвать асинхронно и/или с таймаутом. Затем, когда серверный сокет успешно принимает запрос, он отправляет ответ о успехе - канал связи создан. Канал – это труба м-ду сокетами. Как идёт отправка сообщений? Сперва (в нашем случае) клиент открывает свой сокет, как бы "открывая кран" и "выпуская воду" – сообщение. Затем, после его выпуска, закрывается. "Вода" идёт по каналу вплоть до серверного сокета, и сервер должен знать о приёме сообщения, поэтому серверный сокет параллельно открывается. Затем, если не будет помех, сообщение дойдёт до сервера. После его принятия, сервер прекращает ожидание и закрывает сокет. Наш же клиент отправляет запрос о дисконекте, т. е. об уничтожении канала. Сервер принимает и его, и канал уничножается. Конец!

---

Вот исполнение этой схемы в вашем коде:

```cs
        // определяем id нашего сокета
        var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        // создаём сокет, который работает через интернет и является потоковым
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // устанавливаем id нашего сокета
        socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        // тот самый "спам" (называется прослушиванием) в нашу очередь сообщений
        socket.Listen(5);

        while (true)
        {
            // принимаем клиентский сокет (просто сокет, но с нашим/клиентским конфигом, однако с remoteEndPoint вместо localEndPoint)
            var clientSocket = socket.Accept();
            Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[1024];
            var receivedByteCount = 0;
            var dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // мы не знаем, сколько точно байт пришло, значит нужно извлекать буферами фиксированного размера
            do
            {
                receivedByteCount = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
                dataBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Slice(0, receivedByteCount)));
            } while (clientSocket.Available > 0);

            var data = dataBuilder.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(data);

            socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Success!"));

            // disposing убран, т. к. это задача клиента
            // мы не знаем, а вдруг он ещё захочет послать сообщения?
        }
```